# Android Studio not Generating Boilerplate Java Classes Like MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quick Android Studio question.

Lately I've been creating a lot of new projects in Android Studio and picking the templates like "Blank Activity with Fragment" or "Navigation Drawer Activity" and seeing that it's not generating any Java Classes like it should.

All the /res files get created like normal but there is a lack of any java classes so I have to start from absolute scratch.

While starting from scratch isn't the biggest hassle in the world, I'm curious if I'm just an idiot and have missed a flag somewhere.

here's a shot of the file tree when generating a "Navigation Drawer Activity"

[image]

Info on my Android Studio/Project:

-Building with Target SDK 21, minSDK 14, build tools 21.0.1

-Android Studio version is 0.8.13

Thanks For reading, let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: I have the same problem , someone was able to solve it? I have the latest versions of Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. You will need to disable plug-ins that are not the need. In my case, I have used them from GWT
[image]